# Proving the $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ of $X\sim N(0,1^2) = 1$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I've been struggling with this question for a while now.

Question is on a normal distribution $ f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $, where the $E(X)$ was asked to be found, and hence prove that $\operatorname{Var}(X) = 0$.

After digging around, I discovered that $\int e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$ isn't an elementary function, however is it still possible to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$?

Comment: Yes, but not directly.

Comment: Yes. Will be similar to this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Statistics/Distributions/Normal_(Gaussian)#Variance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
If $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ then $f'(x)=-2xe^{-x^2}$ and $f''(x)=(-2+4x^2)e^{-x^2}$.
Hence
$$\int_{-a}^ax^2e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \int_{-a}^a(\tfrac14f''(x)+\tfrac12f(x))\,\mathrm dx=f'(a)-f'(-a)+ \frac12\int_{-a}^af(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
As we let $a\to\infty$, all that remains is
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}$$